# SpiceJet flight Goa to Hyderabad cancelled but no refund

Tags: air-travel, money, cancellations, refunds, spicejet

I booked four SpiceJet tickets for my return journey Goa to Hyderabad for 15th Dec 2014. 
That day at 9:45 AM I got an SMS "flight cancelled and call us for reschedule". Everybody knows that SpiceJet people never pick up and talk to customers. So I couldn't reschedule. I booked a bus and came back to Hyderabad along with my family, travelling the whole night with lots of pain with my little kids. SpiceJet spoiled our vacation joy.

Now on the SpiceJet site they don't mention anything about a refund.

Do I get my ticket money refunded?
Do I need to do any thing for that?
Will they automatically process a full refund to my card/account?
Can I put a case in a consumer forum for the inconvenience/pain caused?

Comment: You didn't call them, you didn't try to reschedule, and you think they by esp or something will just randomly send you money? What makes you think any business will do that? Yes, getting through is a real hassle. But you can't just *not bother* and then say they owe you a full refund plus extra for the hassle of getting home the way you chose.

Comment: @KateGregory: In fairness, it is not quite clear from the OP's description whether he tried to call the airline and failed to get through, or he gave up without even trying.

Comment: In the USA, if you paid by credit card, you could make a "chargeback" request. I would document the likelihood that you would not have been rescheduled within a reasonable time had you tried (e.g., by reference to the published schedule, or news stories of service disruption).

Comment: @KateGregory: It doesn't seem that unreasonable.  Lots of business will automatically refund their customers if for whatever reason they can't deliver what they promised.  If the flight was booked with a credit or bank card, it's almost certainly possible for the airline to issue a credit back to the same card, without needing anything else from the customer.

Comment: @NateEldredge they texted the passenger asking for a call to reschedule. Not rescheduling can't really be interpreted as requesting a refund. This airline may be collapsing, but for an ordinary airline, it could have been a matter of "the 4pm flight is cancelled; please call us to choose the 5, 6, or 7pm instead." Someone who didn't call or go to the airport and take one of those alternate flights wouldn't exactly be mitigating their losses.

Answer (score 3):

In general, if your flight is cancelled by the airline through no fault of your hown, you're always supposed to have two options:

1. Accepting *their* alternative arrangements, or
2. Getting your money back in full.

They are *not* liable to cover any costs for arrangements you make completely on your own, eg. the bus.  They do also *not* owe you anything for "hassle caused" etc, although most full-service carriers would cover any extra costs incurred (meals, accommodation) and possibly offer you some credit on top, and in some countries ([notably in the EU](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14888/am-i-entitled-to-air-passengers-compensation-if-my-flight-was-cancelled-and-i-di)) there are legal requirements for this too.

However, in this specific case, since [SpiceJet is teetering on the edge of collapse](http://indianexpress.com/article/business/companies/spicejet-needs-r200-cr-to-use-airports-on-credit/), you're going to have a very tough time getting your money back from the airline no matter what you do.  If you paid for the flights by credit card, contact your credit card company/bank immediately and dispute the charge, since you have not received the services you paid for.  If you paid by any other means...  you're likely out of luck, or at best, in for a *long* wait.  Notify the airline in writing that you want your money back, and join the long queue of creditors: according to the news, SpiceJet has unpaid debts of over $300 million USD already.

Comment: Additionally, some, but by no means all Travel Insurance policies can help with the extra costs, eg accommodation or food, in cases when the airline won't/can't.